# How to create if statement inside embedded HTML in JavaScript to show CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display one of two classes based on if there is data in the js array.

**e.g. if there is responseData.title show class grey else class white**

I am trying this now:

```
let resultHTML = '<article class="item">\
                    <div class="post-main">\
                        <header class="clear">\
                            <a href="' + responseData.url + '"</a>\
                            <span class="post-date">just now</span>\
                        </header>\
                        'if (responseData.title) {
                            '<section class="grey">'
                        } else {
                            '<section class="white">'
                        }'\
                            ' + articleImage + '\
                            <h3>' + responseData.title + '</h3>\
                            <div class="post-about">' + responseData.about + '</div>\
                        </section>\
                    </div>\
                </article>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
In your case, it would be like this:

```js
let resultHTML = '<article class="item">\
                    <div class="post-main">\
                        <header class="clear">\
                            <a href="' + responseData.url + '"</a>\
                            <span class="post-date">just now</span>\
                        </header>\
                        ' + responseData.title ?
                            '<section class="grey">'
                        :
                            '<section class="white">'
                        + '\
                            ' + articleImage + '\
                            <h3>' + responseData.title + '</h3>\
                            <div class="post-about">' + responseData.about + '</div>\
                        </section>\
                    </div>\
                </article>';
```

Comment: ninja speed. basically: condition : result if true ? result if false;

Comment: Thanks, will test now.

Comment: @Uby Like this I get only <section class="grey"></section> not the whole <article></article element.>

Comment: The solution is based on @Uby answer to enclose the ternary in (). works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer using [**Template literals (Template strings)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with [**Conditional (ternary) operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is more cleaner.

**Demo:**

```js
let responseData = {title:'abc'}
let articleImage = 'test';
let resultHTML = `<article class="item">
    <div class="post-main">
        <header class="clear">
          <a href=responseData.url </a>
          <span class="post-date">just now</span>
        </header>
        ${
           responseData.title ?
          '<section class="grey">'
          : '<section class="white">'
         }

        ${articleImage}
        <h3> ${responseData.title} </h3>
        <div class="post-about"> ${responseData.about} </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</article>`;
console.log(resultHTML);
```